# How to use command line input in a JavaFX application?

Tags: java, javafx

I am going to develop an application using Java FX. However, I would like to use command line tool to simulate the events instead of key press or button clicks. I tried several implementations but all of them failed. Most of them got stuck and do not take standard input. I also tried multi-threading but also failed. For example the following,

```
    import javafx.application.Application;

    public class Main {
        public Main() {
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Application.launch(Test.class, args);
            CLInput cl = new CLInput();
            cl.start();
        }
    }
```

And in CLInput class I do command line input using Scanner and Test is a simple hello world javafx application.

Anyone has any idea how to do this?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-), "The launch method does not return until the application has exited". So in the code you posted, the `CLInput` object won't even be created until the application exits. You need to start a separate thread for this. [Edit] your question to show how you tried to do this with a background thread.

Comment: Thanks, so I need a separate thread inside javafx application?

Comment: You need a separate thread, somewhere, because you can't block the FX Application Thread to wait for user input. Since you presumably want that thread to invoke code that changes the UI, you need to create it where you can give it access to the UI (i.e. not in the `main` method).